# How do you force a landscape orientation for mobile apps built with cordova-cli?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm using [cordova cli](https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli) to build my app. I want to target both android and ios (maybe more).

As I want this to be true for all platforms, I was hoping I could simply define this as a preference in the config.xml like this:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="landscape" />
```

because this is apparently [how it works](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml) in the phonegap build https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

I assume the features supported in config.xml by phonegap build are different to those by cordova-cli?

I know I can force it in the android app by inserting `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` into my AndroidManifest.xml, but that's no good because it will be over-written the next time I perform a `cordova build`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, it's not possible to set the orientation using a `preference` element in the `www/config.xml`. After inspecting the [cordova-cli code](https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli/blob/master/src/metadata/android_parser.js#L89-L101) it appears that only the version and entry class package are updated in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

For a list of supported preferences see the [Cordova Docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_android_config.md.html#Android%20Configuration).

Added configurations to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file should not be lost on `cordova build`, unless the config option is pulled from somewhere else (i.e. version).

Comment: Thanks. As you mention, the important part is that the manifest is not actually overwritten as I had originally assumed.

Answer (score 10):

This is no longer the case. The "orientation" preference in the config.xml is now honored by the cordova cli starting from version 3.4

This is the corresponding issue : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5634

Comment: brahmana is true : THIS IS NO LONGER THE CASE : please upvote this answer in order to put it more visible as the good updated answer.